# php post web page and return value

Tags: php, post, server, get

I'm doing a test on my local server, that's exactly what I want to do. Post header and payload and return value if incoming data is correct. I couldn't do that. Please help.

```
//post.php
    $base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/requestDeneme/';
    $ch = curl_init($base_url);
    
    $api_headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . "1234"
    );
    
    $api_data = array(
        'client_id' => '1223',
        'client_secret' => '12345',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
    );
    
    $jsonData = json_encode($api_data);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $api_headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print($result);
```

> Blockquote

```
// /requestDeneme/request.php
     <?php
        if ($_SERVER == 'POST') {
            $a = $_GET['Content-Type'];
            $b = $_GET['Accept'];
            $c = $_GET['Authorization'];
    
        

return $a . $b . $c; // or echo $a . $b . $c; I dont know.
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `$_SERVER` contains before you try `if ($_SERVER == 'POST')`?

Comment: [Debugging](https://stackify.com/php-debugging-guide/) is a priceless skill. Familiarize yourself with it. Checking why something doesn't work is better than guessing.